# SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? in Django Model

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django Model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
```

When I try to create an object like below,

```
Tag.objects.create(name='me','created_at'=str(datetime.now()))
```

I get the following error

```
Tag.objects.create(name='me','created_at'=str(datetime.now()))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Naive mistake! I put created_at inside quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typo, you've passed string instead of label

```
Tag.objects.create(name='me', created_at=str(datetime.now()))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model you can use `auto_now_add=True`.

Like this

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And create without manually adding time

```
Tag.objects.create(name='me')
```